# Errors when trying to draw a commutative diagram using an xymatrix

Tags: errors, diagrams, xy-pic

Why is the following code not compiling?

```
\[
    \xymatrix{
       A \ar[rd]^{g \circ f} \ar[r]^f & B \ar[d]^g\\
       C}
\]
```

I'm trying to get a commutative diagram with 3 objects (A, B and C) and 3 arrows (f, g and g ∘ f).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There's a missing `&` before the `C`: just think to a matrix, for the diagram nodes. I'd use `_{g\circ f}` so that the label goes under the diagonal arrow.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing an `&` in the second row

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
  A \ar[rd]_{g \circ f} \ar[r]^f & B \ar[d]^g\\
  & C}
\]
\end{document}
```

It's probably better to put the `g\circ f` label under the arrow.

[image]