# Error messages with diagonal arrows

Tags: errors, diagrams, xy-pic

When I copy and paste the corrected code for example in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58812/errors-when-trying-to-draw-a-commutative-diagram-using-an-xymatrix), I get the following error message:

```
xymatrix 2x2

! Missing number, treated as zero.

to be read again 

                   \/

l.101   & C
}
```

I've been using xymatrix/pic for a while now, and only recently I've been getting weird error messages like these when I try to implement diagonal arrows. What's going on?

ADDENDUM:

So in a basic latex file, the code in question, and any code like it works just fine. So the problem lies in the particular file I'm working in now. What is possibly different about this file?

ADDENDUM II:

I isolated the problem. It turned out what made everything go awry was that I had renewed the command "`\char`" in this file. So, original problem solved. However, can anyone tell me what `\char` had to do with in the compilation of the diagram?

Comment: Please, post your code here.

Comment: @JSeaton Try deleting all precompiled latex files and recompiling. Are you compiling the code with your own or as it is. If you are compiling with some other code then post a MWE.

Comment: The problem may be an incompatibility in packages or package options. In this case, it is necessary to provide a MWE, the packages you are using along with the `xy`. Else, we cannot say what the problem really is. :-)

Comment: @azetina: thank you very much for the helpful comments. I found out what the original problem was (see 'addendum II' above).

Comment: @JSeaton You must *never* redefine primitive commands, unless for *very* specific purposes. Always use `\newcommand` and, if the compiler tells you that the command is already defined and you can't find it in the LaTeX manual, then *don't* redefine it under any circumstance (unless you precisely know what you're doing). In particular, `\char` is used in many places internally and redefining it is really a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had redefined the primitive command `\char`; that was the origin of the error.